# image moves based on text under it

Tags: css

why does my image move around based on whats under it? I have different amounts of text for each description but the images are moving around depending on the amount of lines there are?

```
 <div>
      <img src="img">
      <p>one line</p>
 </div>
 <div>
      <img src="img">
      <p>two lines of text</p>
 </div>




 <style>
     div {
          display:inline-block;
          width:150px;
          text-align:center;
     }
     img {
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
     }
     p {
        padding-top:10px;
      }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a in-line I needed a float:left.